# Python library function to approximate a set of 2D points with a straight line

Tags: python, approximation, linear-interpolation

Given an array with [x, y] points, e.g.:

```
p0 = np.random.rand(21, 2)
p1 = np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3]])
```

I would like to get a straight line [segment] approximation of these points. Least squares method is acceptable, other error functions may be fine too. Note that the set of points in general is not a function, i.e. as shown above in `p1`, there are multiple `y` values associated with `x = 0`.

---

There is no slope, intercept solution for a vertical set of points, e.g. `p1`, therefore `np.polyfit`, `scipy.stats.linregress` are not solutions I'm looking for. Think geometry, not statistics.

Comment: What would be a least-squares solution to this?  Least squares produces a line, `y=f(x)`. 
 What value would you hope to estimate for x=7?

Comment: @TimRoberts For `p1` the solution is `x=0`, i.e. for canonical line equation *ax+by+c=0*, *a=1, b=0, c=0*

Comment: You can use [`scipy.stats.linregress`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.linregress.html#scipy.stats.linregress) among other similar methods

Comment: @CoryKramer No, I can't. Slope/intercept solutions can't handle vertical lines.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but since you're already using `Numpy`, why not just use its `polyfit` function?

```
def fit_line(points):
    r = np.polyfit([p[0] for p in points], [p[1] for p in points], 1)
    print(f"y = {r[0]:.2f}x + {r[1]:.2f}")

fit_line(np.random.rand(21, 2))
# fit_line(np.array([[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3]]))
fit_line(np.array([[0, 3], [1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 6]]))
```

Result:

```
y = 0.20x + 0.51  (different each run)
y = 1.00x + 3.00
```

As you note, the second example is a degenerate case with no slope-intercept form and so `polyfit` throws an exception.  You could catch the exception to deal with that case.  Unfortunately, the library also outputs a bunch of crap to stdout in the degenerate case, making catching the exception less than ideal by itself.  For this reason, I chose to not demonstrate catching the exception but instead just commented out that case.

Comment: As I stated in my question, handling of vertical line is required, so this solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: @Paul - dealing with the vertical line is trivial.  If an exception is thrown, then take the `x` value from any one of your points and produce `x=<value>`.  The problem with this is that it's still a degenerate case because it's not y as a function of x.  If this isn't enough, then I guess I'm wondering what you think the form of a proper answer would look like.  There is simply no way to represent both a purely vertical and a purely horizontal line with a single equation....period.

Comment: Wrong. The canonical line equation, e.g. *ax+by+c=0* can represent ALL straight lines in 2D, including vertical ones.

Comment: Additionally, `np.polyfit` produces a wrong result in cases like this: `[[0, 0], [0, 1], [0.1, 0], [0.1, 1]]`

Comment: Oops..yeah...you're right...I shouldn't have said "equations".  What I meant was that you can't define all lines in terms of a function that maps one coordinate to the other...c1=f(c2).  If you can do something with 'ax+by+c=0', fantastic.